# Как достать текст из БД SQL и поместить в memo

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется таблица БД с двумя столбами id_textb и textb. Как будет выглядить SQL запрос для вывода текста из столба "textb" и помещение его в memo1.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью SQL запроса можно только лишь получить какой-то набор данных.
К примеру, запрос вида

```
SELECT `textb` FROM `table_name` WHERE id_textb = 1
```

вернет, грубо говоря, значение поля `textb`. Это первая часть.
Дальше, Вам требуется это поместить в Memo. Для этого, вам можно сделать что-то подобное:

```
Memo1.Text := textBStr;
```

где `textBStr` это текстовая переменная, куда поместили значение, полученное из запроса. Как все это связать. Вам нужно рассмотреть компоненты для работы с БД, ранее (Delphi 7) это были TADOConnection, TADODataSet, TADOTable, TDataSource, TADOQuery и с ними уже работать.

Пример работы с ADO:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  { Connection string }
  ConnString =
  'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;' +
  'User ID=%s;Password=%s;Data Source=%s;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;' +
  'Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;'+
  'Tag with column collation when possible=False';

  { SQL Query }
  SQLStr = 'SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = :AnId;';

  { User access }
  UserName = 'db_user_name';
  PassWord = 'db_pass_word';
  Server = 'my.db.server';

var
  ADOConn  : TADOConnection;
  ADOQuery : TADOQuery;
  DataSrc  : TDataSource;
  Param    : TParameter;

begin
  { Create an ADO connection }
  ADOConn := TADOConnection.Create(Self);
  { Setup the provider engine }

  { Setup the connection string }
  ADOConn.ConnectionString := Format(ConnString,
    [UserName, PassWord, Server]);

  { Disable login prompt }
  ADOConn.LoginPrompt := False;

  try
    ADOConn.Connected := True;
  except
    on e: EADOError do
    begin
      MessageDlg('Error while connecting', mtError,
                  [mbOK], 0);

      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  { Create the query }
  ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(Self);
  ADOQuery.Connection := ADOConn;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Add(SQLStr);

  { Update the parameter that was parsed from the SQL query: AnId }
  Param := ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('AnId');
  Param.DataType := ftInteger;
  Param.Value := 1;

  { Set the query to Prepared - will improve performance }
  ADOQuery.Prepared := true;

  try
    ADOQuery.Active := True;
  except
    on e: EADOError do
    begin
      MessageDlg('Error while doing query', mtError,
                  [mbOK], 0);

      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  { Create the data source }
  DataSrc := TDataSource.Create(Self);
  DataSrc.DataSet := ADOQuery;
  DataSrc.Enabled := true;

  { Finally initilalize the grid }
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSrc;
end;
```

Подробно можно посмотреть вот тут - http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOConnection.html

Answer (score -1):

Вот рабочий код, кому нужно ловите

```
Form24.SQLQuery1.Close;
Form24.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form24.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT textb from name_textb WHERE id_textb = 1');
Form24.SQLQuery1.Open;
Memo1.Lines.add(Form24.SQLQuery1.Fieldbyname('textb').AsString);
Form24.SQLQuery1.Next;
```

Comment: Этот код не несет никакой полезной нагрузки. В вашем случае куча всего спрятана в дизайнере формы, было бы куда полезнее объяснить хотя бы в виде схемы со связами, какие компоненты вы использовали и как они связаны. В Вашем случае это как минимум (возможно) TADOConnection и TADOQuery, что тоже осталось в фоне.